# CMake: Why makes this string comparison result no sense?

Tags: string, cmake

I'm inside a CMake macro and I'm doing this:

```
if ( "${type}" STREQUAL "lib" )
    message( "cond OK: ${type}" )
else()
    message( "cond KO: ${type}" )
endif()
```

And guess what it sometimes outputs?

```
cond OK: prg
```

How the hell could that happen?

I can't send the whole CMake code, and neither could I isolate the problem to a short example, because, obviously, if you isolate this to a simple macro you call, it always works fine (and shows `message( "cond OK: lib" )` or `message( "cond KO: prg" )`). It only gets to wrong behaviour when I'm entering the macro many times upon my huge project generation (and I could not isolate that...).

Comment: And how should we help? It is most probably a bug in your software. Reduce the code, until the problem vanishes, then you have found the problem.

Comment: @usr1234567: I completely disagree, whatever software is present on top of that, there is absolutely no reason for this condition test to return false when the strings are definitely equivalent. One may help by pointing out a syntax issue....as Tsyvarev is trying to.

Comment: Maybe you are right, regarding Tsyvarev's answer...

Comment: @usr1234567: If you're the one who donwvoted, please reconsider that ;-)

Comment: Is there are any relation between `type` variable and macro arguments? (E.g., `type` is an argument the macro or deduced from it). BTW, can you post *full macro definition*, which contains given comparision? No needs to explain variables/macro/functions, used within this macro.

Comment: Yes, `type` is a parameter of the macro, does it make any difference? `MACRO( FIND_DEPENDENCIES_LIST modules_list found depends type verbose )` I cannot post the whole contents, it's really huge...

Answer (score 1):

When compare value of variable which is definitely exist, **use variable's name as argument for "if" command**, not a result of its dereference. More correct comparision is

```
if (type STREQUAL "lib")
```

The thing is that in some flows "if" command **attempts to dereference its string argument**.

E.g., for the right hand argument "if" checks whether `lib` variable exists. If so, it uses *value of `lib` variable* for comparision [That's why it is bad practice to use variables with names same as string constants, used by the project].

Full list of cases, when dereference attempt takes a place, see in the "if" command [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html).

---

In you case you can observe

```
cond OK: prg
```

if there is variable `prg` defined and set to "lib".

Because first argument ( `${type}` ) is evaluated to `prg`, "if" checks, whether variable with this name exists. Because the variable is actually exists, its value ("lib") is actually used for comparision. That's why result of comparision is true.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunatly ${lib}, ${prg} are both unset. I even tries ${${lib}} and ${${prg}}, they are all empty strings....could it be something else?

Comment: You output values of `${lib}` and `${prg}` within same macro invocation, are you? BTW, it is better to check variable's existence using `if(DEFINED ${type})` and `if(DEFINED lib)`.

Comment: By the way, note that changing "MACRO" to "FUNCTION" fixes the problem and apparently behaves OK....(could be a solution?)

Comment: *Macro arguments are not true variables* (see its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/macro.html#macro-argument-caveats)). Probably, this is the origin of the problem. But you use `${type}`, not a `type`... As for changing MACRO to FUNCTION - it could be OK, but also may break functionality in case your macro code set variables for being used by the caller. E.g., if `found` argument is *output parameter*, within function body it should be set with `SET(${found} <value> PARENT_SCOPE)`.

Comment: As my advice `if (type STREQUAL "lib")` doesn't work for macro argument, you can create *true* variable inside macro and use it instead: `set(_type ${type})` `if(_type STREQUAL "lib")`. Can you check whether this approach works? (without changing MACRO to FUNCTION).

Comment: `set(_type ${type})` does not fix it. I think the easiest may be to swith MACRO to FUNCTION (variables in this macro are all local...). You may extend your answer so that I can accept it!?

Comment: I will try to investigate this some times later.